# If the minimal polynomial has the degree of the characteristic polynomial in a real space, are they equal?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying *Linear Algebra Done Right* (2nd ed) by Axler.  In chapter 8 in the section on the minimal polynomial, he says

> Suppose $V$ is a complex vector space and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$.  The Cayley-Hamilton theorem and [$q(T) = 0$ iff the minimal polynomial of $T$ divides $q$] imply that the minimal polynomial of $T$ divides the characteristic polynomial of $T$.  Both these polynomials are monic.  Thus if the minimal polynomial of $T$ has degree $\operatorname{dim} V$, then it must equal the characteristic polynomial of $T$.

I see that he specifically said "Suppose $V$ is a complex vector space," but for the life of me I cannot see why this would not hold in a real vector space.  Cayley-Hamilton holds in both real and complex spaces, and I cannot find anything in Axler's introduction about the minimal polynomial that requires $V$ to be complex either.  Yet, flipping ahead to chapter 9 when he specifically proves Cayley-Hamilton in real spaces, he doesn't revisit this criterion for the minimal and characteristic polynomials to be equal.  Neither have I been able to find any notes or questions and answers on the web to speak to this.

So does this hold for real spaces as well, or not?

Comment: Yes, it holds in general.

Comment: The minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial, and they are both monic. So yes.

Comment: Yes, the comment above about the minimal polynomial equaling the characteristic polynomial if the two polynomials have the same degree holds for real vector spaces as well as complex vectors spaces. The reason that the comment you quoted refers just to complex vector spaces is that it occurs in Chapter 8 (Operators on Complex Vector Spaces). The characteristic polynomial for an operator on a real vector space is not defined until Chapter 9 (Operators on Real Vector Spaces).

Comment: omg the man himself!  i *love* your book!  I wanted to ask you my question personally but I wasn't sure if I'd get an answer!  :-D